# Пользовательский элемент из класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть тут люди которые помогут разобраться с созданием кастомных элементов для WPF C#?

Единственное что я умею, это создавать класс в проекте, давать ему наследование от элемента и вызывать его в коде XAML с помощью

```
<local:Class1/>
```

Но как заполнять эти элементы? например если сам класс принимает значение на вход?

```
public Class1(string srt) : base()
```

как в таком случае в коде XAML установить значение str?

Comment: Никак. XAML не поддерживает конструкторы с параметрами. Используйте свойства (зависимости). Можно, конечно, придумать какой-нибудь хак, например, с использованием расширений разметки, но не зная задачи трудно что-то советовать

Comment: а как тогда создать пользовательский элемент что бы можно было его использовать в XAML и вводом значений? интернет сёрфил, ответов не могу найти которые будут понятны чайникам

Comment: Свойства зависимости, я же написал. Вот пример: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level18/18_2.php